# Alternate colours of a bunch of div elements (without using tables)

Tags: css, html

Essentially, what I have in mind is a bunch of div elements, and I want to alternate colours. I could do this using IDs, but I want to use classes to minimize the amount of extra (and potentially spaghetti) code needed.

```
<div id="divs">
    <div class="bla">
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bla">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've already tried nth-child, but it didn't work.

Edit: And I want to keep the hr.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `<hr>` element, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu99x/)

HTML

```
<div id="divs">
    <div class="bla">bla</div>
    <div class="bla">bla</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.bla:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
div.bla:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: to add to that, if you want to add <hr> under every item, use border-bottom and if your last div does not need it, use :last-child